# Tabs and Form Submit

Tags: forms

I have an app that has multipla page tabs. One of the tabs has a form that does a search. The issue I am running is that when I do a search on the form, and then go to a different tab, and then come back, it does the search again. How can I make it so that when I switch tabs and come back that the form is in its default state.

Thanks much for the help.

Comment: I've met a same situation what i did was i found the `#` of the tab and altered the form submit respectively . May be there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the following within the submit button tag:

```
onclick="return false"
```

Comment: This will not at all allow the form to submit. he is asking about preventing the submission on particular situation.

Comment: @Mathankumar OP not asking about preventing the submission on particular situation, read again.

Comment: @Bobby, what will this `onclick="return false"` do ?